# I have created character human in blender. How to use it in Java/Android

Tags: opengl, java, android, models, blender

Title says it all pretty much. I can't find anything online which explains it in details. I have created a character model in Blender and I want to use it in Android app. I want to make it move. What's my next step here?

Comment: You haven't specified how do you do rendering. It's like asking how to print certain information from database on page and don't specify language used to generate pages - php, perl, java ee,...

Comment: @Miro OpenGL is probably the best for Java?

Comment: You can also use an engine to render stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use libgdx. It's open source game engine. [Here is example of importing 3D model from Blender](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ImportingModelsFromBlender)

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the model into your app. When you read the model file, you'll be able to load a list of coordinates for all the vertices that make up your model, and information such as which vertices connect to each other to form polygons (faces). Then when you perform your rendering in your app, you take the coordinates of your vertices and plot them in your 3D space. If your model has animations, the file will have information on what the vertex coordinates should be at each frame of the animation. You use this information to 'animate' your model.

How you do this is up to you. You could do it from scratch for example. Write your own model file parser to store all the vertex coordinates in your program for rendering. Or you can use a library, for example a premade .obj loader, along with more sophisticated graphics libraries that have support for animations.